# Converting string to binary then xor binary

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am trying to convert a string to binary then xor the binary by using the following methods

```
def string_to_binary(s):
    return ' '.join(map(bin,bytearray(s,encoding='utf-8')))

def xor_bin(a,b):
    return int(a,2) ^ int(b,2)
```

When I try and run the `xor_bin` function I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: exceptions.ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 2: '0b1100010 0b1111001 0b1100101 0b1100101 0b1100101'
```

I can't see what's wrong here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code that's causing the `ValueError` exception (and presumably using one or both of the functions).

Answer (score 2):

`bin` is bad here; it doesn't pad out to eight digits (so you'll lose data alignment whenever the high bit is a `0` and misinterpret all bits to the left of that loss as being lower magnitude than they should be), and it adds a `0b` prefix that you don't want. `str.format` can fix both issues, by zero padding and omitting the `0b` prefix (I also removed the space in the joiner string, since you don't want spaces in the result):

```
def string_to_binary(s):
    return ''.join(map('{:08b}'.format, bytearray(s, encoding='utf-8')))
```

With that, `string_to_binary('byeee')` gets you `'0110001001111001011001010110010101100101'` which is what you want, as opposed to `'0b1100010 0b1111001 0b1100101 0b1100101 0b1100101'` which is obviously not a (single) valid base-2 integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear because you don't show how the two functions you defined where being used when the error occurred — therefore this answer is a guess.

You can convert a binary string representation of an integer into a Python `int`, (which are stored internally as binary values) by simply using passing it to the `int()` function — as you're doing in the `xor_bin()` function. Once you have two `int` values, you can xor them "in binary" by simply using the `^` operator — which again, you seem to know.

This means means to xor the binary string representations of two integers and convert the result back into a binary string representation could be done like this you one of your functions just as it is. Here's what I mean:

```
def xor_bin(a, b):
    return int(a, 2) ^ int(b, 2)


s1 = '0b11000101111001110010111001011100101'
s2 = '0b00000000000000000000000000001111111'
#    ---------------------------------------
#    '0b11000101111001110010111001010011010'  expected result of xoring them

result = xor_bin(s1, s2)
print bin(result)  # -> 0b11000101111001110010111001010011010
```